# Find the disc of convergence of the following power series (complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the disc of convergence of the following power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^{2n}}{3^nn}$$

I have figured a couple of these out. I have tried several of the test (geometic series, ratio test, root test...) but I seem to get stuck each time. What would be the best way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test does it:
$$
\frac{\left| \dfrac{(z-i)^{2(n+1)}}{3^{n+1}(n+1)} \right|}{\left|\dfrac{(z-i)^{2n}}{3^nn}\right|} = \frac 1 3 \cdot |z-i|^2 \cdot \frac n {n+1} \to \frac{|z-i|^2} 3 \text{ as } n \to\infty.
$$

$$
\frac{|z-i|^2} 3 < 1 \text{ iff } |z-i|< \sqrt3.
$$

So the circle of radius $\sqrt3$ centered at $i$ is it.

Answer (score 0):

Using ratio or root test for complex number series (with a parameter $z$) you should get absolute convergence exactly for
$$
|z-i|^2<3\iff |z-i|<\sqrt3.
$$
You could also explore the coefficient sequence that has alternatingly, for odd indices, the value zero. Then only the root test works, and you have to use the limes superior to get the radius of convergence.